# Trac notifications (smtp) and Postfix

Tags: postfix, smtp, trac

I've two separate ubuntu 12.04 servers.

1. Runs Trac (homeserver/Dyndns)
2. Runs postfix (VPS/staticIP)

I configured trac to use TLS and connect to postfix server.

Trac config:

```
admit_domains =
always_notify_owner = true
always_notify_reporter = true
always_notify_updater = true
ambiguous_char_width = single
email_sender = SmtpEmailSender
ignore_domains =
mime_encoding = base64
sendmail_path = sendmail
smtp_always_bcc =
smtp_always_cc = sandro@weare.de.com
smtp_default_domain =
smtp_enabled = true
smtp_from = trac@weare.de.com
smtp_from_name = Trac
smtp_password = randompassstring==
smtp_port = 587
smtp_replyto = trac@weare.de.com
smtp_server = vps.idev.ge
smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
smtp_user = trac@weare.de.com
ticket_subject_template = $prefix #$ticket.id: $summary
use_public_cc = false
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = true
```

When I try to send notification, Trac says:

```
ERROR: Failure sending notification on change to ticket #1: SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure')
```

Postfix says:

```
Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[78.139.167.29]: TLSv1.1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
warning: SASL authentication failure: incorrect digest response
warning: unknown[78.139.167.29]: SASL CRAM-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure
```

postconf -n output is

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
delay_warning_time = 4h
disable_vrfy_command = yes
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
masquerade_domains = vps.idev.ge www.idev.ge !sub.idev.ge
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
mydestination =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = vps.idev.ge
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:::1:10023, permit
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/apache2/ssl/vps.idev.ge/PositiveSSLCA2.crt
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/apache2/ssl/vps.idev.ge/vps.idev.ge.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/apache2/ssl/vps.idev.ge/vps.idev.ge.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_limit_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit_override = yes
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
virtual_maildir_limit_message = Sorry, the user's maildir has no space available in their inbox.
virtual_overquota_bounce = yes
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Any thoughts what is happening here?

Comment: Is your Trac capable of authenticating via `CRAM-MD5`, have you tried forcing `PLAIN` or anything other?

Comment: @sebix I don't know. The only option Trac provides is use_tls flag. I dug out this though: http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/7670

Comment: @sebix my postfix authenticates just fine using AUTH PLAIN, or AUTH LOGIN (via telnet). It is trac that has problems I think.

Comment: Have you tried making the [changes](http://trac.edgewall.org/attachment/ticket/7670/notification.py.patch) proposed in this issue from 6 years ago? But only for diagnostics please. I think we should dig further in the authentication mechanism provided by your postfix/SASL. Could you find out what you are using and how it is configured? EDIT: What auth mechanism are allowed? You saw that in your telnet session. If there's a MD5, then it's weird in your SASL. If not, I suspect Trac of being weird.

Comment: @sebix I think we are getting closer. I cannot get through AUTH CRAM-MD5. My postfix in theory supports: AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5

Comment: @sebix unfortunatly trac 12 is different, I cannot find those lines anywhere.

Comment: @sebix I think thanks to you, I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEST:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect vps.idev.ge:587
```

`AUTH PLAIN, AUTH LOGIN` was working fine. It appears `CRAM-MD5` and `DIGEST-MD5` are not functioning correctly.

Trac seeing better methods was trying to use them, but faild. In trac there is no fallback mechanism.

Temporary fix in `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.con`

```
#mech_list: plain login cram-md5 digest-md5
mech_list: plain login
```

Obviously this is not a good solution. Good one would be to fix CRAM-MD5 and DIGEST-MD5. But this will do temporarily.